# Is there a general concrete implementation of a KeyedCollection?

Tags: .net, collections

The [System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132439.aspx) class is a very useful alternative to [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), especially when the key data is part of the object being stored or you want to be able to enumerate the items in order. Unfortunately, the class is abstract, and I am unable to find a general concrete implementation in the core .NET framework.

The [Framework Design Guidlines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613) book indicates that a concrete implementation *should* be provided for abstract types (section 4.4 Abstract Class Design). Why would the framework designers leave out a general concrete implementation of such a useful class, especially when it could be provided by simply exposing a constructor that accepts and stores a [Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y.aspx) from the item to its key:

```
public class ConcreteKeyedCollection<TKey, TItem> : KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>
{
    private Converter<TItem, TKey> getKeyForItem = null;
    public ConcreteKeyedCollection(Converter<TItem, TKey> getKeyForItem)
    {
        if (getKeyForItem == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("getKeyForItem"); }
        this.getKeyForItem = getKeyForItem;
    }
    protected override TKey GetKeyForItem(TItem item)
    {
        return this.getKeyForItem(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are concrete implementations, including (but not limited to):

- [KeyedByTypeCollection<TItem>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404549(VS.80).aspx) (I use this class frequently)
- [MessageHeaderDescriptionCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.messageheaderdescriptioncollection.aspx)

To the spirit of your question, no there is no generic implementation and since I do not work for Microsoft I could only speculate. Since the concrete implementation is as easy as you've shown, I won't offer any speculation (as it would probably be wrong).

Answer (score 4):

Here is the implementation I came up with

```
public class LookupKeyedCollection<TKey, TItem> : KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>
{
    private Func<TItem, TKey> _getKeyFunc;

    public LookupKeyedCollection(Func<TItem, TKey> getKeyFunc)
    {
        _getKeyFunc = getKeyFunc;
    }

    //Required KeyedCollection implementation
    protected override TKey GetKeyForItem(TItem item)
    {
        return _getKeyFunc(item);
    }

    public bool TryGetItem(TKey key, out TItem item)
    {
        if (Dictionary == null)
        {
            item = default(TItem);
            return false;
        }

        return Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out item);
    }

    public void AddOrUpdate(TItem item)
    {
    Remove(_getKeyFunc(item));
    Add(item);
    }

    public new bool Contains(TItem item)
    {
        return base.Contains(_getKeyFunc(item));
    }
}
```

The reasoning behind the methods can be mostly found in the following:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20081123034725/http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework/topic62318.aspx
- http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/03/numericallykeyedcollection

Comment: What's the `public new bool Contains(TItem item)` method for?

Comment: See the first link (it was broken, so I switched to the wayback machine )

Comment: Better call it `TryGetItem`.

Comment: @nawfal I believe the point is to mask the original `Contains`, which arguably has the wrong semantics.

Comment: @OhadSchneider I meant you can rename `TryGetValue` to `TryGetItem`. The latter conveys correct meaning in the context of KeyedCollection.

Comment: If Dictionary is not set, it should not return false, but iterate over the list as here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2922554-add-a-method-bool-trygetitem-tkey-key-out-titem-i

Comment: Well I feel compelled to point out that a KeyedCollection _does_ allow adding key-less items. Thus the "clever" improvement of Contains is technically wrong, because it could return false for an item that _is_ in the collection! MSDN: `You can add items without a key, but these items can subsequently be accessed only by index.` This happens when trying to add an item and the key-method returns null - _which it is allowed to do_, and when that happens the item is added to the collection key-less! (To clarify it is _not_ added with a key of null - null is not allowed as key in c# dictionaries!)

Comment: In other words the "bug" reported in the link you provided is arguably false. The only bug in that example code is that a) none of those people read the documentation properly and b) the items added to the collection doesn't implement Equals properly. With default Equals from the object class that example failing should be expected, if you carefully read the documentation that is. However this might not be obvious and one can argue that a framework class with confusing non-intuitive behavior is bad design. They could have called them ContainsKey and ContainsItem (latter exists but is private).

Comment: @OhadSchneider ...Anyway one somewhat more correct implementation for your new Contains method would be `var key = _getKeyFunc(item); return key == null ? Items.Contains(item) : base.Contains(key);`. Where `Items` is a protected property in the Collection-class, which KeyedCollection inherits from, and it returns an `IList<TItem>` of _all_ items, including those which does _not_ have a key. However even this is technically wrong, because the item _could still exists in the collection under a different key._ This "absurd" property is what most people don't understand about KeyedCollection.

Comment: ...Yes! KeyedCollection _does_ allow explicitly setting an arbitrary key for an item - that key does _not_ have to match what the key-method returned! So in other words the only correct way to check if a KeyedCollection contains an "item" is by linear search - there is no other correct way! Allowing keys to be changed arbitrarily is a weird design - but the reason is that we have no guarantee that `TItem` is immutable - so they made it possible to change keys for items in case items are mutated - arguably they could have added a re-evaluate method instead. Seal the class to guard against this.

Comment: Some of you might be thinking _"Linear search for finding an item in a KeyedCollection? That's absurd!"_ but no, wrong again. Think closely about it: KeyedCollection is a hybrid between a list and a dictionary. What is the complexity of finding an item in a list? O(n). What is the complexity of finding a _value_ in a dictionary? Also O(n)! So what is the reasonable complexity of finding a value in a list-dictionary hybrid? O(n) would seem like the most obvious answer really...

Answer (score 1):

The reason that there's no concrete implementation is that it won't be serializable (you can't serialize a delegate). All collections in the BCL are serializable.

That's why it's better to inherit and override the method, especially when you can't predict how the collection is going to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that I came up with.  It either hard codes the property names or you can use the [Key] attribute if you'd like.

```
    ///// <summary>
///// Creates an indexed list.  Requires that [Key] attribute be applied to a property in TValue object.
///// </summary>
///// <example>
///// public class Test
///// {
/////     [Key]
/////     public int Id { get; set; }
///// }
///// 
///// IndexedList<int, Test> tests;
///// </example>
///// <typeparam name="TKey"></typeparam>
///// <typeparam name="TValue"></typeparam>
public class IndexedList<TKey, TValue> : KeyedCollection<TKey, TValue>
{
    PropertyInfo keyProperty;

    public IndexedList()
    {
        foreach (var property in typeof(TValue).GetProperties())
        {
            // this requires .net 4, which I couldn't use due to the WPF shadow effect deprication
            //if (property.PropertyType == typeof(TKey) && property.IsDefined(typeof(KeyAttribute), true))

            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(TKey) && (property.Name.ToUpper() == "ID" || property.Name.ToUpper() == "KEY"))
            {
                keyProperty = property;
                return;
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Unable to find a property in {0} that is named Id or Key and is of type {1}.", typeof(TValue).Name, typeof(TKey).Name));
    }

    protected override TKey GetKeyForItem(TValue item)
    {
        return (TKey)keyProperty.GetValue(item, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: "IndexedList" sounds a little redundant. A list is basically indexed in .NET. It doesnt give the idea of keyed indexing either. "KeyedList" sounds better.