# Insert only if new else update in BindingList

Tags: c#, .net, list, bindinglist

Hi I have a custom BindingList Containing Products with the following information

```
string ProductID
int Amount;
```

How would I make it possible to do the following.

```
ProductsList.Add(new Product("ID1", 10));
ProductsList.Add(new Product("ID2", 5));
ProductsList.Add(new Product("ID2", 2));
```

The list should then contain 2 Products

```
ProductID = "ID1"   Amount = 10
ProductID = "ID2"   Amount = 7;
```

So It workes kind of like a Shopping Cart

Im looking at the AddingNew Event and override void InsertItem(int index, T item)

But I could really need a little help getting started

Comment: what did you tried till yet ? Please post some code

Comment: Not much, don't really have any code for it yet. Still looking for documentation

Comment: Though my best bet would be the  protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item) and if its a new product call base.InsertItem(index, item); else do the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i really don't know why you require this custom list as there are many good collections in the .net library but i have tried something below.

```
 public class ProductList
{
   public string ProductID {get;set;}
   public int Amount {get;set;}
}

public class MyBindingList<T>:BindingList<T> where T:ProductList
{

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {

        var tempList = Items.Where(x => x.ProductID == item.ProductID);
        if (tempList.Count() > 0)
        {
           T itemTemp = tempList.FirstOrDefault();
           itemTemp.Amount += item.Amount;


        }
        else
        {
            if (index > base.Items.Count)
            {
                base.InsertItem(index-1, item);
            }
            else
                base.InsertItem(index, item);

        }

    }

    public void InsertIntoMyList(int index, T item)
    {
        InsertItem(index, item);
    }



}
```

and in the client code where you can use this list.

```
        ProductList tempList = new ProductList() { Amount = 10, ProductID = "1" };
        ProductList tempList1 = new ProductList() { Amount = 10, ProductID = "1" };
        ProductList tempList2 = new ProductList() { Amount = 10, ProductID = "2" };
        ProductList tempList3 = new ProductList() { Amount = 10, ProductID = "2" };

        MyBindingList<ProductList> mylist = new MyBindingList<ProductList>();

        mylist.InsertIntoMyList(0, tempList);
        mylist.InsertIntoMyList(1, tempList1);
        mylist.InsertIntoMyList(2, tempList2);
        mylist.InsertIntoMyList(3, tempList);
        mylist.InsertIntoMyList(4, tempList1);
        mylist.InsertIntoMyList(0, tempList3);
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your solution, works perfectly, though I skipped InsertInfoMyList and just use the Add method.

Answer (score 1):

Creating your own collection is rarely the right choice - I would favor containment rather than inheritance in this case. Something like

```
class ProductsList
{
    private readonly SortedDictionary<string, int> _products 
                                   = new Dictionary<string,int>();

    public void AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        int currentAmount;
        _products.TryGetValue(product.ProductId, out currentAmount);

        //if the product wasn't found, currentAmount will be 0
        _products[product.ProductId] = currentAmount + product.Amount;
    }
}
```

Comments:

- If you need an actual IEnumerable (as opposed to a dictionary), use a [KeyedCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842652/is-there-a-general-concrete-implementation-of-a-keyedcollection/3297478#3297478)
- Instead of creating your own class (which forces you to implement all the methods you want), you can write an extension method for `IEnumerable<Product>`, something like `AddProduct` - but that won't hide the regular `Add` method do I guess it's more of a quick and dirty way of doing it

Lastly, don't worry about the `IBindingList` part - you can always use a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx)

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear, but I need to use my own collection, since I need my list to be Sortable and at the same time support INotifyPropertyChanged. I just removed most of the code to make this question as simple as possible.

Comment: You're confusing simple data binding (binding to properties of an object) - which requires INotifyPropertyChanged, with complex data binding (binding to a list) - which requires IBindingList. Indeed, if you look at saurabh's collection, it doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged at all (since BindingList<T> doesn't). And like I said, you get IBindingList for free from any collection by using a BindingSource. With regards to sorting, adding it is very simple, for example you could use a SortedDictionary (see above). Bottom line is, creating your own collection is more error prone and redundant